# What is wrong with this URL Redirect code? Multiple query string values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

I am getting the strangest behavior from my URL Rewrite code.  It is a .NET application and the code is in the config file.  All other rewrites are working as expected.

URL to rewrite:

http://www.example.com/projects/offer_details.aspx?artistID=64&projectID=100&recordID=1353&selection=1&salesTypeID=6

The Code:

```
<rule name="OrderDetails" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^projects/offer_details.aspx$" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="artistID=(\d+)" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="projectID=(\d+)" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="recordID=(\d+)" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="selection=(\d+)" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="salesTypeID=(\d+)" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="/OfferDetails/{C:1}/{C:2}/{C:3}/{C:4}/{C:5}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
```

Here is what I am seeing in Fiddler:

GET /OfferDetails/64?artistID=64&projectID=100&recordID=1353&selection=1&salesTypeID=6

It looks as if it is catching the first param and the page fine but it is ignoring all of the other values and adding the query string even though appendQueryString="false".

This is what it should redirect to:

http://www.example.com/projects/OfferDetails/64/100/1353/1/6

Any ideas?  I'm stumped.  Restarted the site.  Cleared all caches and nada.

Comment: I tested this rewrite rule and it worked fine. Are there other rewrite rules in your application ? Perhaps another rule matches the request first

Comment: @redoc do you see same issue across different browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Was not able to replicate your issue. It'll be helpful, if you could post your config file.

However, there is another issues I found in the rewrite rule. Your redirect url should be `/projects/OfferDetails/{C:1}/{C:2}/{C:3}/{C:4}/{C:5}` and not `/OfferDetails/{C:1}/{C:2}/{C:3}/{C:4}/{C:5}`.

```
<rule name="OrderDetails" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^projects/offer_details.aspx$" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="artistID=(\d+)" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="projectID=(\d+)" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="recordID=(\d+)" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="selection=(\d+)" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="salesTypeID=(\d+)" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="/projects/OfferDetails/{C:1}/{C:2}/{C:3}/{C:4}/{C:5}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```